# Finding who answered a question in the Stack Overflow dataset dump

Tags: support, data-explorer

Is there a way to know who (user_id) answered a question on Stack Overflow from the Stack Overflow dataset tables?

I am thinking it should be in the `Posts` table, but I couldn't find a clue.

Comment: UserIds in rows of the Posts table correspond to the UserId of a row in the Users table. There's an author name field (`OwnerDisplayName`) for posts, but it only gets filled in for posts where the author was deleted (and possibly disassociated from the post too?). You can see the full SEDE table reference guide with all the ins-and-outs here: [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677)

Comment: @zcoop98 **So do you mean the UserIds in rows of the Posts table correspond to the userId of the who answered a question?** I was thinking the UserIds in rows of the Posts is the UserId of the person that asked the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Posts table you'll find Question (PostTypeId = 1)  and Answers (PostTypeId = 2). The user who posted the Post is stored by its Id in the OwnerUserId field. If a user profile gets deleted the OwnerUserId is set to null and the OwnerDisplayName is populated instead.

When you've found a Question in the Posts table (PostTypeId = 1) you can find the Answers for that Question by finding the rows in the Posts table that have the same ParentId as the Posts.Id of the Question.

Via the Answers you'll find also the OwnerUserId in each Answer row.

This method works for both the Data Explorer as well as for the Data Dump.

Here is a [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1441233) to demonstrate above explanation:

```
select q.id [question.id]
     , q.title
     , q.answercount
     , a.id [answer.id] 
     , a.owneruserid [answer.owneruserid]
from posts q 
inner join posts a on a.parentid = q.id
where q.id = 4
order by q.id, a.id
```

Result:

[image]

See also: [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)